# Stability of SCIPY.NNLS solution on two overlapping A matrices

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, scipy, linear-algebra

I have the following code:

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import array
from scipy.optimize import nnls

def by_nnls(A=None, B=None):
    """ Linear programming by NNLS """
    #print "NOF row = ", A.shape[0]
    A = np.nan_to_num(A)
    B = np.nan_to_num(B)

    x, rnorm = nnls(A,B)
    x = x / x.sum()
    # print repr(x)
    return x


def f(arrA, arrB):
    """ Check if two matrices overlap"""
    return not set(map(tuple, arrA)).isdisjoint(map(tuple, arrB))
```

Basically it runs Linear Programing by using [NNLS](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.0/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.nnls.html). By taking matrix `A` and vector `B`. And I have two sets of those: `A1 B1` and `A2 B2`.
And A1 is subset of A2, and B1 is subset of B2.

```
B1 = array([  22.133,  197.087,   84.344,    1.466,    3.974,    0.435,
          8.291,   45.059,    5.755,    0.519,    0.   ,   30.272,
         24.92 ,   10.095])
A1 = array([[   46.35,    80.58,    48.8 ,    80.31,   489.01,    40.98,
           29.98,    44.3 ,  5882.96],
       [ 2540.73,    49.53,    26.78,    30.49,    48.51,    20.88,
           19.92,    21.05,    19.39],
       [ 2540.73,    49.53,    26.78,    30.49,    48.51,    20.88,
           19.92,    21.05,    19.39],
       [   30.95,  1482.24,   100.48,    35.98,    35.1 ,    38.65,
           31.57,    87.38,    33.39],
       [   30.95,  1482.24,   100.48,    35.98,    35.1 ,    38.65,
           31.57,    87.38,    33.39],
       [   30.95,  1482.24,   100.48,    35.98,    35.1 ,    38.65,
           31.57,    87.38,    33.39],
       [   15.99,   223.27,   655.79,  1978.2 ,    18.21,    20.51,
           19.  ,    16.19,    15.91],
       [   15.99,   223.27,   655.79,  1978.2 ,    18.21,    20.51,
           19.  ,    16.19,    15.91],
       [   16.49,    20.56,    19.08,    18.65,  4568.97,    20.7 ,
           17.4 ,    17.62,    25.51],
       [   33.84,    26.58,    18.69,    40.88,    19.17,  5247.84,
           29.39,    25.55,    18.9 ],
       [   42.66,    83.59,    99.58,    52.11,    46.84,    64.93,
           43.8 ,  7610.12,    47.13],
       [   42.66,    83.59,    99.58,    52.11,    46.84,    64.93,
           43.8 ,  7610.12,    47.13],
       [   41.63,   204.32,  4170.37,    86.95,    49.92,    87.15,
           51.88,    45.38,    42.89],
       [   81.34,    60.16,   357.92,    43.48,    36.92,    39.13,
         1772.07,    68.43,    38.07]])

B2=array([   5.144,   30.771,   22.133,    0.   ,    0.427,    0.   ,
          1.329,  197.087,   84.344,    1.466,    3.974,    0.435,
          8.291,   45.059,    5.755,    0.519,   21.662,   41.665,
          5.544,    0.482,    1.953,    4.214,    0.576,    0.   ,
         30.272,    2.262,   24.92 ,   30.32 ,    0.948,    1.107,   10.095])
A2 = array([[   29.95,    36.96,    51.68,    35.95,    34.18,    49.8 ,
           30.47,  4565.08,    34.25],
       [   29.95,    36.96,    51.68,    35.95,    34.18,    49.8 ,
           30.47,  4565.08,    34.25],
       [   46.35,    80.58,    48.8 ,    80.31,   489.01,    40.98,
           29.98,    44.3 ,  5882.96],
       [   26.  ,   151.76,  2850.8 ,    64.88,    29.08,   110.99,
           23.67,    23.69,    25.84],
       [   26.  ,   151.76,  2850.8 ,    64.88,    29.08,   110.99,
           23.67,    23.69,    25.84],
       [   26.  ,   151.76,  2850.8 ,    64.88,    29.08,   110.99,
           23.67,    23.69,    25.84],
       [   19.33,    23.2 ,    28.65,    22.05,  5271.38,    24.4 ,
           20.88,    20.28,    23.45],
       [ 2540.73,    49.53,    26.78,    30.49,    48.51,    20.88,
           19.92,    21.05,    19.39],
       [ 2540.73,    49.53,    26.78,    30.49,    48.51,    20.88,
           19.92,    21.05,    19.39],
       [   30.95,  1482.24,   100.48,    35.98,    35.1 ,    38.65,
           31.57,    87.38,    33.39],
       [   30.95,  1482.24,   100.48,    35.98,    35.1 ,    38.65,
           31.57,    87.38,    33.39],
       [   30.95,  1482.24,   100.48,    35.98,    35.1 ,    38.65,
           31.57,    87.38,    33.39],
       [   15.99,   223.27,   655.79,  1978.2 ,    18.21,    20.51,
           19.  ,    16.19,    15.91],
       [   15.99,   223.27,   655.79,  1978.2 ,    18.21,    20.51,
           19.  ,    16.19,    15.91],
       [   16.49,    20.56,    19.08,    18.65,  4568.97,    20.7 ,
           17.4 ,    17.62,    25.51],
       [   33.84,    26.58,    18.69,    40.88,    19.17,  5247.84,
           29.39,    25.55,    18.9 ],
       [   21.18,  4213.22,  1172.23,    39.19,    33.68,    32.09,
           17.48,    47.11,    26.52],
       [   21.18,  4213.22,  1172.23,    39.19,    33.68,    32.09,
           17.48,    47.11,    26.52],
       [   23.61,    28.03,    22.92,    27.01,    24.62,    27.2 ,
           23.86,    23.1 ,   925.26],
       [   23.61,    28.03,    22.92,    27.01,    24.62,    27.2 ,
           23.86,    23.1 ,   925.26],
       [   23.61,    28.03,    22.92,    27.01,    24.62,    27.2 ,
           23.86,    23.1 ,   925.26],
       [  111.35,    24.3 ,    42.06,    23.83,   118.74,    21.12,
         1464.47,    86.8 ,   157.35],
       [  111.35,    24.3 ,    42.06,    23.83,   118.74,    21.12,
         1464.47,    86.8 ,   157.35],
       [   42.66,    83.59,    99.58,    52.11,    46.84,    64.93,
           43.8 ,  7610.12,    47.13],
       [   42.66,    83.59,    99.58,    52.11,    46.84,    64.93,
           43.8 ,  7610.12,    47.13],
       [   21.01,    14.49,     9.62,    19.74,    10.73,  2396.79,
           15.9 ,    11.78,    10.06],
       [   41.63,   204.32,  4170.37,    86.95,    49.92,    87.15,
           51.88,    45.38,    42.89],
       [ 2500.99,    60.14,    59.  ,    64.74,    72.4 ,    61.48,
           64.68,    51.07,    51.89],
       [   62.61,   121.71,   161.71,  2949.63,    74.98,    82.22,
           63.01,   719.7 ,    72.93],
       [   62.61,   121.71,   161.71,  2949.63,    74.98,    82.22,
           63.01,   719.7 ,    72.93],
       [   81.34,    60.16,   357.92,    43.48,    36.92,    39.13,
         1772.07,    68.43,    38.07]])
```

Then I find something strange.
The solution of a particular point exist in A1 but it becomes 0 in A2. This is how it looks:

```
In [9]: by_nnls(A=A1,B=B1)
Out[9]:
array([ 0.70089761,  0.        ,  0.06481495,  0.14325696,  0.01218972,
        0.        ,  0.02125942,  0.01906576,  0.03851557])

In [10]: by_nnls(A=A2,B=B2)
Out[10]:
array([ 0.72020358,  0.0992065 ,  0.04161968,  0.04371648,  0.00698775,
        0.        ,  0.        ,  0.03533024,  0.05293576])
```

Sixth (0-based) solution of `A1` gives 0.02125942 but in `B2` yield 0.
Why is that? How can I resolve this issue?

My understanding is that as you add more evidence (i.e. rows) the value should
increase. Perhaps that intuition was wrong?

If you'd like to verify whether A1 is subset of A2:

```
In [15]: f(A1,A2)
Out[15]: True
```

Comment: I don't see any issues. The more data you add the more reliable the results will be but that doesn't mean that they will increase.

Comment: @gsmafra: Thanks. What's the best way to prove what you said in LP context? My boss wouldn't believe the LP system, due to the different solutions of As.