# How to add regularization in Scipy Linear Programming (Non-negative Least-Squares)

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, linear-algebra

Here is my LP code using [Scipy's NNLS](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.0/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.nnls.html):

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import array
from scipy.optimize import nnls

def by_nnls(A=None, B=None):
    """ Linear programming by NNLS """
    #print "NOF row = ", A.shape[0]
    A = np.nan_to_num(A)
    B = np.nan_to_num(B)

    x, rnorm = nnls(A,B)
    x = x / x.sum()
    # print repr(x)
    return x

B1 = array([  22.133,  197.087,   84.344,    1.466,    3.974,    0.435,
          8.291,   45.059,    5.755,    0.519,    0.   ,   30.272,
         24.92 ,   10.095])
A1 = array([[   46.35,    80.58,    48.8 ,    80.31,   489.01,    40.98,
           29.98,    44.3 ,  5882.96],
       [ 2540.73,    49.53,    26.78,    30.49,    48.51,    20.88,
           19.92,    21.05,    19.39],
       [ 2540.73,    49.53,    26.78,    30.49,    48.51,    20.88,
           19.92,    21.05,    19.39],
       [   30.95,  1482.24,   100.48,    35.98,    35.1 ,    38.65,
           31.57,    87.38,    33.39],
       [   30.95,  1482.24,   100.48,    35.98,    35.1 ,    38.65,
           31.57,    87.38,    33.39],
       [   30.95,  1482.24,   100.48,    35.98,    35.1 ,    38.65,
           31.57,    87.38,    33.39],
       [   15.99,   223.27,   655.79,  1978.2 ,    18.21,    20.51,
           19.  ,    16.19,    15.91],
       [   15.99,   223.27,   655.79,  1978.2 ,    18.21,    20.51,
           19.  ,    16.19,    15.91],
       [   16.49,    20.56,    19.08,    18.65,  4568.97,    20.7 ,
           17.4 ,    17.62,    25.51],
       [   33.84,    26.58,    18.69,    40.88,    19.17,  5247.84,
           29.39,    25.55,    18.9 ],
       [   42.66,    83.59,    99.58,    52.11,    46.84,    64.93,
           43.8 ,  7610.12,    47.13],
       [   42.66,    83.59,    99.58,    52.11,    46.84,    64.93,
           43.8 ,  7610.12,    47.13],
       [   41.63,   204.32,  4170.37,    86.95,    49.92,    87.15,
           51.88,    45.38,    42.89],
       [   81.34,    60.16,   357.92,    43.48,    36.92,    39.13,
         1772.07,    68.43,    38.07]])
```

The usage:

```
In [9]: by_nnls(A=A1,B=B1)
Out[9]:
array([ 0.70089761,  0.        ,  0.06481495,  0.14325696,  0.01218972,
        0.        ,  0.02125942,  0.01906576,  0.03851557])
```

My question is how to add [regularization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regularization_(mathematics)) factor in the LP system there?
I'm open to solution other than using Scipy.

Answer (score 5):

You can express the regularized (assuming typical, diagonal Tikhonov) Least-Squares problem by extending the `A` matrix with a diagonal matrix containing the square root of the weights for each variable and adding zeros to your `b` vector.

```
lamb = 1
n_variables = A1.shape[1]

A2 = concatenate([A1, sqrt(lamb)*eye(n_variables)])
B2 = concatenate([B1, zeros(n_variables)])

by_nnls(A=A2, B=B2)
```

Try extending the new cost function into a sum and you will see that it is exactly the same as adding a `norm(lambda * x) ** 2` term into it.

Comment: How to choose `lambda` score?

Comment: That is a different and complex question. Try googling "regularization parameter selection". The best thing you can do is to have a true ``x`` ground and cross-validate your model.

Comment: Do you mind looking at my related question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35405183/stability-of-scipy-nnls-solution-on-two-similar-a-matrices

Comment: About the other comment (I cannot edit it anymore), you don't need to have a true ``x`` ground to cross-validade your model. Actually this would only make sense if this is an estimation (and not a prediction) problem.